# Can direct speech lead to ambiguity when spoken?

Tags: grammar

For example I tell my friend:

> Tell her 'I Love you'

Since he is not going to see the quotation marks
he might perceive it as

> *Tell her I love you*

And he might end up telling her

> 'He loves me'

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you speak :)

In the case of:

> Tell her 'I Love you'

you should actually say:

> Tell her:  [............] 'I Love you'

Notice the (short) pause in speech between the two parts. Also, the tone of the voice is different in the two parts:

- "tell her" - stronger voice, it is an order / advice;
- "I love you" - a romantic voice.

---

It is quite possible that sometimes confusions will happen, but that is not specific to English only.

Comment: yeah but I'd rather prefer indirect speech, atleast in this case

Comment: Of course, indirect speech is better. You asked if direct speech can be used and if it can lead to confusion - and I answered that question.